# Apply jQuery only in a new content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to inject some html using jQuery, just before some element like this:

```
$(element).before(content);
```

This content has some typeahead controls, so I need to call:

```
$('.ajax-typeahead').typeahead( ....
```

to make these control to become "typeahead".

The problem is that my page already had some Typeahead controls already configured and calling above command, mass all of them.

There is a way to apply this command only in the new content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before injecting the newly generated HTML element, attache the event handler to them.

```
   $(element).before($('new content').find('newly created selectors').typeahead());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to achieve this: one is to call `typeahead` on the content prior to insertion into the DOM. The content has to be a jQuery object, e.g. `$('<div>...</div>')` or the likes.

```
var newContent = content.find('.ajax-typeahead').typeahead(...);
$(element).before(newContent);
```

However, this trick may fail under certain circumstances, such as for plugins that require computation of element dimensions — element dimensions are not computed prior to DOM insertion.

The alternative method is to perform DOM transversal using `.prev()`. However, not knowing how your content is, it might be a good idea to wrap them with a `<div>` or a semantically relevant element (e.g. `<article>`, `<section>`...)

```
$(element)
.before(content.wrap('<div />'))    // Wrap content in <div> and insert prior to $(element)
.prev('div')                        // Transverse the DOM to access the inserted <div>
.find('.ajax-typeahead')            // Find element with the class .ajax-typeahead
.typeahead(...);                     // Call typeahead()
```